# How can the wrap search option come up?

Tags: eclipse, search

In Find/Replace, there is not any option for wrap search.
How can I install or setup the plugin?
My Eclipse version is 3.4.2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your dialog is just too small vertically. Resize the dialog and the extra options should be shown.